# Is there any support for combining Pact Magic with Magic of Incarnum?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am looking for anything in Dragon Magazine or 3rd party material that supports combining Pact Magic from Tome of Magic with Soulmelds from Magic of Incarnum.

Answer (score 15):

Why *yes*, I did write up a highly acclaimed combination of these two. It was, unfortunately, hosted on a forum that has since died, but luckily the Wayback Machine has it, and so I present [the midnight occultist](https://web.archive.org/web/20160707022547/http://forum.faxcelestis.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=22), a prestige class combining *Tome of Magic* pact magic with *Magic of Incarnum* meldshaping. I have started a process of rehosting, reformatting, and revising the class [in this Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cvgj3UT6IDFThblJxp5zJPioYYGIFZyx8NaxkSrSv3E/edit?usp=sharing).

Aside from the midnight occultist, I am not aware of any other combination of these two. There definitely isn’t an official one, and a “true” third-party one would be nearly impossible as neither *Tome of Magic* nor *Magic of Incarnum* is available under any open license. Homebrew is the only realistic option, and as far as I’m aware, mine is the only one.

Comment: Thank you! Did you happen to ever expand it to other vestiges outside Tome of Magic? I am looking to play Age if Worms and I understand The Green Lady was developed for it.

Comment: @ColdIronAntler Well, I did Ashardalon, who is from _Dragon Magic_ rather than _Tome of Magic_. I never did the web enhancement or _Dragon_ magazine vestiges (who you see listed in the last post), nor any non-WotC ones. The Green Lady appears to have been done by James Jacobs (today best known as one of the Pathfinder leads at Paizo) as a solo/homebrew effort. I didn’t know about that until just now, and I can’t actually find a copy of it anywhere, though. If you have a link to a copy of her vestige stats, I’d take a look.

Comment: Here is the original post by James Jacobs: https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2h3qh?The-Green-Lady   (13th post in the thread I think) I really appreciate this.  I have been looking at what you did for the other vestiges and it is really cool and flavorful.

Comment: @ColdIronAntler Kind of like a melding of Karsus and Tenebrous there, I suppose. Pretty neat. Seems a little better than other 2nd-level vestiges, but meh. I’ll give it some thought.

Comment: Perhaps the 2nd and 4th level abilities of the prestige class here https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/classes/prestigeDunmag/apostleOfTheGreenLady.html would be a good basis for binds.  No idea what a totem bind might look like though.

Comment: @ColdIronAntler I have started the process of rehosting/reformatting/revising the midnight occultist in a Google Doc, including [The Green Lady](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cvgj3UT6IDFThblJxp5zJPioYYGIFZyx8NaxkSrSv3E/edit#heading=h.63yfyfaasxk6). Didn’t end up using the apostate abilities (mostly because I forgot that existed), but I’m pretty pleased with what I came up with.

Comment: I like it.  It’s straightforward and elegant.  Not as powerful as others but since the vestige is a bit over tuned to begin with, I think it works.

Comment: @ColdIronAntler “Not as powerful as others but since the vestige is a bit over tuned to begin with, I think it works.” Yeah, that was definitely some of my thinking. Though Divine Soultouch is a **very** good feat to have when you have turn/rebuke undead on a cooldown and you have abilities (per the basic effect and investment) to bypass that cooldown.

Comment: Just curious, in your new revision are you also planning on designing chakra pacts for the web enhancement and *Dragon* magazine vestiges that were left as a "TO DO" in the original post?

Comment: @ObliviousSage I’ve done the three psionic vestiges, because I had an idea for them. The others will only happen if I think of something, I guess. Zceryll, in particular, is problematic because she’s _already_ wildly overtuned, so adding _more_ to that vestige seems questionable. But also like, Astaroth (the crafting one) has so many rules holes that it’s really hard to work with since I don’t know how any given table is going to rule on it.